# Should we stop to use kruskal function of agricolae package for post-hoc (multiple comparisons) tests?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

Lot of people use the `kruskal` function of the [`agricolae`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/agricolae/index.html) package (R) to make multiple comparisons.

If they do so, it means that they want to apply a **non-parametric test** to conclude if there is, at least, one group different from an other. And then (when the null hypothesis is rejected), apply multiple comparisons to know which group is different from an other.

BUT, according to [the documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/agricolae/man/), [`kruskal` function](https://rdrr.io/cran/agricolae/man/kruskal.html) of the `agricolae` package uses "the criterium Fisher’s least significant difference (LSD)", which is based on t-tests, which are **parametric tests**...

It is well known that after a significant Kruskal-Wallis test, the most common post-hoc tests are Dunn test or Conover test. Not t-tests ! Hence my question, should we stop to use this function for post-hoc tests ?

Comment: To comment on part of the software piece of the question:  The *PMCMRplus* package has several post-hoc tests for Kruskal-Wallis ( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PMCMRplus/index.html ).  For the Dunn (1964) test, I often use the *FSA* package, just because I like the output.